# Prerequisites for Cox's Galois Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am planning to read Cox's book 'Galois theory' but I don't know any abstract algebra. In the preface which you can read [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3u4RF8SrRooC&pg=PR3&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) there is no indication of the assumed knowledge. Could someone please tell me if it is self-contained and if I can understand it if I don't know any abstract algebra?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to read Galois theory without knowing abstract algebra? Additionally he has placed some basic concepts in the appendix so I would assume he expects a solid command over algebra.

Comment: @Nitin: I don't know I'm just in high school and read about Galois theory and got interested. So I definitely need to study algebra first? - Thanks

Comment: Page 25 already deals with "The Polynomial Ring in n Variables" without introducing what a ring is $\Rightarrow$ I think you will be lost.

Comment: Dummit and Foote is the go-to book for abstract algebra. It reads like an encyclopedia, has extremely clear proofs, and an array of problems of all difficulty levels. It starts from the most basic definitions and goes to Galois theory and rep theory.

Comment: @Nitin: Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: If you haven't seen abstract algebra before, you might find something like Gallian's book much more easy-going than Dummit & Foote.